# Stop Reportviewer from refreshing when timer ticks

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I'm trying to create a report host in vs2010 using asp.net. This is the first time I've tried doing web development so I may be making a very obvious mistake. The end goal is a host that not only shows a report to the user, but also tracks how long they are looking at the report. However, I can't get past this annoying issue that every time my timer ticks the report is redrawn.

I have a UsageAuditor control, it's just an update panel with a timer and a label in it:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Timer runat="server" ID="Timer1" Interval="3000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"/>
    <asp:Label ID="lblTime" runat="server" Text="Not updated yet"></asp:Label>
</ContentTemplate>
```

Then my report shell uses that control:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"/>
    <uc1:UsageAuditor ID="ua1" runat="server" />
    <rsweb:reportviewer ID="reportViewer" runat="server"  Font-Names="Verdana" 
        Font-Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" ProcessingMode="Remote" 
        WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" 
        Height="800px" Width="1000px" AsyncRendering="True">            
    </rsweb:reportviewer>
</form>
</body>
```

And the timer tick simply updates the label:

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblTime.Text = String.Format("Updated at {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString());
}
```

So I thought by definining my ReportViewer outside of the UpdatePanel the UpdatePanel would redraw iteself, but the rest of the page would not get updated. However, every time the timer ticks it redraws the report. It's very annoying because if you have the calendar control open on the report it closes it. Currently for testing purposes the timer ticks every three seconds which is not realistic, but I still don't want the report control getting redrawn when the user is trying to use it regardless of the interval. Any ideas?

Comment: if it were me, I would move the timer to the client with something like jquery or plain javascript. (instead of doing it on the server). If that is possible, it will solve your issue and be more efficient in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found a post saying [ReportViewer and UpdatePanel do not mix](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsreportcontrols/thread/3c555eb9-6bc2-4155-8233-67462d45fdd1):

> Due to the way the report viewer uses script, it is currently not compatible with an UpdatePanel.  We are aware of this problem and looking into the necessary changes to get the ReportViewer working in an UpdatePanel.  But at present, there is no work around.  While it may appear you can get simple reports working in this scenario, some of the more subtle report viewer behavior will still be broken, such as its code that keeps the report session alive when the browser window is left open.

After reading puddleglums suggestion I put some thought into why I felt I needed to use a timer to update my usage information. It really was unneccessary to upate on an interval if I could just capture when the user left the page.

Following [this example](http://codeasp.net/blogs/raghav_khunger/microsoft-net/609/calling-codebehind-or-server-side-code-on-page-unload) I added some java script to call a server side function on close:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    function HandleClose() {
        var QAid = document.getElementById('QAReportRequest');
        PageMethods.SetReportViewEndTime(QAid.value);
    }
    //]]> 
</script>
```

Added the HandleClose call on onunload and the hidden type to my body:

```
<body onunload="HandleClose()">
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <input id="QAReportRequest" type="hidden" runat="server"/>
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"/>
  <rsweb:reportviewer ID="reportViewer" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" 
    Font-Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" ProcessingMode="Remote" 
    WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" 
    Height="800px" Width="1000px">
  </rsweb:reportviewer>          
  </form>
</body>
```

Then created a server side function:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static void SetReportViewEndTime(string ID)
    {
        QAReportingManager manager = new QAReportingManager();
        QAReportUsageResponse element = manager.GetQAReportUsage(long.Parse(ID));
        QAReportUsageRequest request = new QAReportUsageRequest
        {
            ID = element.ID,
            userID = element.userID,
            userName = element.userName,
            reportName = element.reportName,
            startTime = element.startTime,
            endTime = DateTime.Now,
            department = "Unknown"
        };
        manager.SaveQAReportUsage(request);
    }
```